# Spring batch JdbcPaging Item Reader with multiple table joins

Tags: oracle, pagination, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

Need to implement paginating for an spring batch application. The Query has multiple join, Guide for an effective Pagining query, with existing table model can this join be effectively written to pagination where "ED_EMP_LOGIN_STATE" is the filter where other tables are select. running this query is still slow and look likes paginzation with rownnum condition does not show any impact on execution plan.

How this query can be modified to pass in spring batch paginzation reader

```
<bean id="empItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="empDataSource" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="org.sample.model.EmployeeMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="empDataSource" />
            <property name="sortKeys">
                <map>
                    <entry key="ID" value="ASCENDING"/>
                </map>
            </property> 
            <!-- Intentionally put sort key second in the query list as a test -->
            <property name="selectClause" >
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[
                            emp_task_sub_details.DEP_NAME AS DEP_NAME 
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.EmpName AS EmpName 
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.EmpFirstName AS EmpFirstName
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.EmpIDCard AS EmpIDCard
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.EmpBuilding AS EmpBuilding
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.EmpLocation EmpLocation ENV_CAT
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.NAME AS NAME
                            ,ed_parent_join.task_name AS TASK_NAME
                            ,ed_parent_join.start_time AS TASK_NAME_START_TIME
                            ,ed_parent_join.finish_time AS TASK_NAME_END_TIME
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.STATUS AS STATUS
                            ,emp_task_sub_details.STATE_ID AS ID
                    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
            <property name="fromClause">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[   
                        ED_EMP_LOGIN_STATE ed_parent_join
                        JOIN (
                                select
                                ed_dep.name as DEP_NAME
                                ,empName_code_prop.string as EmpName
                                ,empfirst_code_prop.string as EmpFirstName
                                ,id_code_prop.string as EmpIDCard
                                ,build_code_prop.string as EmpBuilding
                                ,loc_code_prop.string as EmpLocation
                                ,ed_emp.name as NAME
                                ,ed_emp_lg_st.id as STATE_ID
                                ,ed_emp_tas_wk.STATUS AS STATUS
                                from
                                ED_DEPARTMENT ed_dep
                                ,ED_EMPLOYEE ed_emp
                                ,ed_emp_tas_wkK ed_emp_tsk
                                ,ED_EMP_LOGIN ed_emp_lg 
                                ,ED_EMP_LOGIN_STATE ed_emp_lg_st 
                                ,ED_EMP_LOGIN_WORK ed_emp_tas_wk
                                ,ED_TASK_PROPS empName_code_prop
                                ,ED_TASK_PROPS empfirst_code_prop
                                ,ED_TASK_PROPS id_code_prop
                                ,ED_TASK_PROPS build_code_prop
                                ,ED_TASK_PROPS loc_code_prop
                                ,ED_ACTIVITY ed_act
                                ,ED_LOCATION ed_loc
                                where
                                ed_emp.id = ed_dep.id
                                and ed_emp.tsk_id = ed_emp_tsk.id
                                and ed_emp_lg.tsk_id = ed_emp_tsk.id
                                and ed_emp_lg_st.parent_emp_id = ed_emp_lg.id
                                and ed_emp_tas_wk.state_id = ed_emp_lg_st.id
                                and ed_emp_lg.prop_id = empName_code_prop.parent_prop_id
                                and empName_code_prop.name = 'EmpName'
                                and ed_emp_lg.prop_id = empfirst_code_prop.parent_prop_id
                                and empfirst_code_prop.name = 'EmpFirstName'
                                and ed_emp_lg.prop_id = id_code_prop.parent_prop_id
                                and id_code_prop.name = 'EmpIDCard'
                                and ed_emp_lg.prop_id = build_code_prop.parent_prop_id
                                and build_code_prop.name = 'EmpBuilding'
                                and ed_emp_tas_wk.JOB_ID = ed_act.id
                                and ed_act.environment_name = ed_loc.name 
                                and ed_loc.prop_id = loc_code_prop.parent_prop_id
                                and loc_code_prop.name = 'EmpLocation')  emp_task_sub_details 
                                ON emp_task_sub_details.STATE_ID = ed_parent_join.id        
                    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
            <property name="whereClause">
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[   
                        ed_parent_join.start_time >= :startTime
                        and ed_parent_join.finish_time < :finishTime        
                    ]]>
                </value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="${loadPageCommitSize}" />
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="startTime" value="#{jobParameters[StartTime]}" />
            <entry key="finishTime" value="#{jobParameters[FinishTime]}" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: When you execute this query on DB through any client, how much time it takes ? And the same when you execute using Spring Batch, how much time it takes ? Also try to set `setFetchSize` to 500 and see the difference.

Comment: It almost take same time in client as well in application,tried with fetch size as 100 as i had page size as 100. Te time it take with rownum appended and without rownum also same time, Hence i think the query join to be corrected

Comment: So if I understand correctly your question is about performance, the reader is working as expected. Is that correct?

Comment: yes there is related to performance, if this can be rewritten to pass to paging reader objects